# Pandas Check for mulitple minimum consequtive criterias

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, criteria, minimum

I have a scenario where I want to check for a minimum criterion (0.6) being met over consecutive pandas dataframe rows in a column (`Col1`), which also meets a criterion when the starting value is at least (0.7) i.e.:

```
Col1
0.3
0.5
0.55
0.8 = true
0.65 = true
0.9 = true
0.61 = true
0.3
0.6
0.67
0.74 = true
0.63 = true
0.61 = true
```

In other words, the check would be `True` if the value is at least 0.7, or if the value is at least 0.6 and the previous values are at least 0.6 with the first value in the consecutive series being at least 0.7.

It will be running off a very large data set so needs to be efficient.  I am thinking something with `shift()` would work...but can't get it quite right.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Series.where()` to construct the logical Series.

*Steps*:

- initialize the Series with `nan` values;
- assign True for all values larger than 0.7
- assign False for all values smaller than 0.6
- forward fill values between 0.6~0.7 as it depends on previous values
- fill possible missing values at the beginning of the Series
- convert the dtype to boolean (optional)

so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df['check'] = np.nan
df['check'] = (df['check'].where(df.Col1 < 0.7, True)
                          .where(df.Col1 > 0.6, False)
                          .ffill().fillna(False)
                          .astype(bool))
```

[image]

Comment: Very clever! Thank you!

Comment: how might I use this check logic as a select criteria of col1 without creating a new column called 'check'? I.e. df.col1.loc (...meets your check criteria...). If possible I would like to use to use .loc ()

Comment: You can do `df.Col1[df.check]` for subsetting and then drop the check column. If you really don't want to create a new column for some reasons, `s = pd.Series([np.nan] * df.shape[0], index = df.index); df.Col1.loc[s.where(df.Col1 < 0.7, True).where(df.Col1 > 0.6, False).ffill().fillna(False).astype(bool)]`